# LobiPanel does not load Bootstrap panel positions from localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, local-storage

Does anybody know how saving panel positions (in localStorage) works with LobiPanel's stateful option in Bootstrap?

The [documentation](http://lobianijs.com/site/lobipanel) says one must use the stateful option in order to save the position among it's siblings and it will apply them when you reload the browser.

Unfortunately when I do a reload on my site, the panel positions are always back to it's initial state.

It doesn't work, even though LobiPanel successfully adds parent keys and values to the Local Storage, e.g.:

```
lobipanel_parent_BKlPfuXKuW:"{"panel-2":0,"panel-3":1,"panel-1":2}"
lobipanel_parent_KyCQKms0ir:"{"panel-1":0,"panel-2":1,"panel-3":2}"
lobipanel_parent_lDSURxUHh2:"{"LwmEvZSUiF":0,"vpT9FMcurP":1,"awfVUjhLzE":2}"
lobipanel_parent_lk5lsV9Y3k:"{"panel-6":0,"panel-5":1,"panel-4":2}"
```

So the positions are actually saved to Local Storage but are somehow not applied when reloading.

This is how my HTML code (Bootstrap v3.3.5) looks like:

```
<div id="lobipanel-multiple lobipanel">
    <h3>Multiple panels with drag & drop</h3>
    <p>Drag panels by clicking on the headers</p>
    <div class="bs-example">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 panel">
                <div class="panel panel-default" data-index="0" data-inner-id="panel-1">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title">
                            <h4>Panel title 1</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel body 1
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-warning" data-index="1" data-inner-id="panel-2">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title">
                            <h4>Panel title 2</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel body 2
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-danger" data-index="2" data-inner-id="panel-3">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title">
                            <h4>Panel title 3</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel body 3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 panel">
                <div class="panel panel-success" data-index="3" data-inner-id="panel-4">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title">
                            <h4>Panel title 4</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel body 4
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-info" data-index="4" data-inner-id="panel-5">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title">
                            <h4>Panel title 5</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel body 5
                    </div>
                </div>
               <div class="panel panel-danger" data-index="5" data-inner-id="panel-6">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title">
                            <h4>Panel title 6</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel body 6
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.panel').lobiPanel({
            sortable: true,
            stateful: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

In the documentation there is example code for the stateful function but only for a single panel and not positions. So I still don't know how to address the CSS properly.

```
<!-- Stateful -->
<div>
    <h3>Stateful. <small>Saves its state in localStorage</small></h3>
    <div class="bs-example">
        <div id="lobipanel-stateful" class="panel panel-default" data-inner-id="lobipanel-stateful">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title">
                    Panel title
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                Panel body
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#lobipanel-stateful').lobiPanel({
            stateful: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: according to the docs you reference, `stateful` should be an integer not a boolean. And you need to specify `data-inner-id`. Did you read the docs you reference?

Comment: Yes, I did read the docs and did specify the `data-inner-id` attributes in the divs as you can see in my code above. In the docs there is example code for the stateful function but only for a single panel and not positions. It uses the boolean `true` for the stateful function and is working fine, so this should not be the issue.

Comment: I added the example code from the docs in my main post. But it unfortunately does not show how to address the CSS properly when saving panel positions.